# How to make the user enter a positive double variable?

Tags: c++

I want the user to enter a positive double variable. If they enter anything else, I want the program to loop and continue to ask them to enter a number instead of getting an error and closing. I made an infinite loop with a conditional statement and a break. For some reason if they enter something other than a positive number it infinitely asks for the the radius. Can someone help me with this?

```
for(;;) {
    cout << "Radius: ";
    cin >> radius;
    if(radius > 0){
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean if they enter something like `x`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make user give input until he enter X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691737/make-user-give-input-until-he-enter-x)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply check the stream state of `cin`:

```
    double radius;
    for(;;) {
        cout<<"Radius: ";
        if(!(cin>>radius) || radius < 0.0) {
             cout << "Invalid input, please enter a positive double value." << endl;
             cin.clear();
             std::string dummy;
             cin >> dummy; // Read the left invalid input
        }
        else {
           break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried using this and for some reason it still goes infinitely when I enter something other than a double.

Comment: @vsoftco Yes, THX for pointing out. I've chosen to read a dummy string up to the next whitespace/return.

Comment: Ok it works now. I don't understand the std: part and the cin >> dummy. Could one of you explain what that means to me?

Comment: @Suds2 The `std::` part explicitly specifies `string` being used from the `std` namespace. The `cin >> dummy;` statement reads up any invalid characters left at the input stream.

Comment: @Suds2 you may find this link helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input

Comment: Also instead of using cin >> dummy I used getline(cin, dummy) so that when someone inputted something with spaces it would prompt them only once instead of prompting them however many words they inputted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear the stream's error flags, otherwise you keep looping, since no more other reads are performed when the stream is in a bad state, and `radius` keeps its value before the loop. You need to do the following (must `#include <limits>`):

```
if(!(cin >> radius)) // we didn't read a number, cin has a "bad" state
{
    cin.clear(); // clear the error flags
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // ignore the rest
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! What does the "!" mean? I'm new to c++.

Comment: @Suds2 means `not`, i.e. negation. `cin >> radius` returns a stream, which is convertible to `bool`. Whenever the read operation is successful, the conversion results in `true`, otherwise is `false`. So the `if` is executed whenever `cin >> radius` is converted to `false`, e.g. bad read.